# Azure Cognitive Search: add multiple suggesters to a single index

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm trying to add multiple suggesters to an Azure Search index, but receive this error response:

> An index cannot have more than one suggester with searchMode='analyzingInfixMatching'

The property on the index is called `suggesters` and is of type `array`.
The documentation states:

> The *only* mode currently supported is *analyzingInfixMatching*

Is the api defined to support future capabilities? Or am I overlooking an option that will enable me to add multiple suggesters?

And to understand why: 
I have fields in my index for different languages. I would like a suggester only to include the field for the language the current user has specified.
With the current implementation I can only provide suggestions or autocomplete based on all available languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I work on the Azure Cognitive Search team. As you guessed, the schema is designed to be adaptive to future changes but at the moment only one suggester is supported - analyzingFixMatching.

If I understand correctly, you want to apply suggestions selectively only on fields specified by user at query time. You can achieve that through *searchFields* property of suggestions API. Define a suggester with all the fields that can potentially be specified by users and then limit the required ones using the above property.

More details here - https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/suggestions

Comment: For anyone who wants to check the documentation, here is a [direct link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-suggesters#property-reference) to Suggestor class property reference where it states "The only mode currently supported is analyzingInfixMatching, which currently matches on the beginning of a term."